# mocha & chai, how can I mock expect result?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

My source code:

```
function getElementCountOfArray(arr) {
    var countObj = {};
    arr.forEach((element) => {
        if(countObj[element]) {
            countObj[element] ++;
        } else {
            countObj[element] = 1;
        }
    });

    return countObj;
}

module.exports = getElementCountOfArray;
```

my test code:

```
describe('getElementCountOfArray', function() {

    it('test case 1', function() {
        var numArray = [2, 2, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9];

        var result = {
            2: 2,
            3: 1,
            6: 1,
            7: 4,
            8: 1,
            9: 1
        };

        expect(getElementCountOfArray(numArray)).to.eql(result);
    });
});
```

the `result` is calculate by myself, I really think is not correct.

If the `result` is complicated data structure, calculate manually is not  a good idea. I could make a mistake about the `result`.

So, what's the "correct" way to simulate the `expect` result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this how the unit tests are supposed to work. The result that is returned by your SUT(System Under Test) i.e the method you are testing, is a product of the processing done in the SUT. To test the SUT **you must know before hand what the final outcome should be**. This is why it advisable to test the SUT result with a simple stubbed expected value, **something that you are confident is correct**. Of course, some results can be complicated data structures, but you can choose to stub the expected structure using just one or two elements.

Again, the expected value, no matter how complex, must be easily verifiable and simple enough to be able for someone to arrive at using a dry run of the SUT. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for anwser. Can not understand completely, is that mean I have to give the final `result` to `expect`? If so, I have to run the `function` in my head and give the `result`.

Comment: I meant when you do `expect(actual result).to.eql(expected result)`, you have to very much calculate the 'expected result' in your head. To make it easy, may be  just consider a very simple data structure. E.g  in your case you can simply use numArray = [2, 2] to calculate the expected result.

Comment: But I think simple case can not test good enough. Maybe I should make my `function` as little as possible? So it can be test easily.

Comment: Ok. Also you try think of inputs to the function as distinct cases. For example, since your SUT has a if else there only two different values needed to test these conditions. You can also try passing a undefined or empty array.